Unstable statistical coefficient among different specifications
I ran a fuzzy regression discontinuity and tested different polynomial degrees and bandwidths to assess the robustness of the results. Specifically, I used four polynomial degrees (1–4) and seven bandwidths (ranging from ±1 to ±6.9, the latter being optimal in terms of the variance-bias tradeoff). This resulted in 28 estimations, of which 27 were positive with relatively high effect sizes (the remaining one was negative, but pretty close to 0). Among these, 13 were statistically significant at a 90% confidence level, 15 at a 89.8% CL and 20 at a 85% CL. If I reduce the results only to polynomials of degree 1 and 2 (as some recommend), the percentage of statistically significant coefficients is practically the same.
One possible explanation for the instability in statistical significance could be the relatively low statistical power, which is around 30%–40% at a 0.2 SD minimum detectable effect size —a common threshold in the literature for the same intervention on  outcomes of similar nature. This occurs because my first stage is not great, although not  bad either (a 33 percentage points difference in the probability of treatment) and despite the # of observations ranging from 2500 to 16000 for different bandwiths.
Also, the instability only arises when I use Cataneo's robust standard errors. When I use just the bias-corrected standard errors, every coefficient is positive and statistically significant.
What would you conclude from this? Given that the power is low it can't be said anything about the true effect? Or could it be at least said that there is evidence of a positive effect, but that the lack of consistency calls for caution?
